# SQL Server : delete where string value contains another value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete, sql-like, sql-in

I want to delete from table all records which selected string value contains in another value from another table (with ignore case sensitive).

For example: if `value1="Hello"` (from one table) and `value2-"Hello word"` (from another table), then that record should be deleted.

```
DELETE FROM [table1] 
WHERE value1 LIKE  '%' + (SELECT value2 FROM [table2]) + '%'
```

But that SQL statement returns an error.

Comment: Will only work if table2 contains 1 row.

Comment: Add sample table data - for both tables - and also table1's data after the delete.

Comment: what is the error returned? you may wish to look at `CONCAT()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an exists criteria:

```
delete
from Table1 T1
where exists (select T2.value2 from Table2 T2 where T1.value1 like '%'+T2.value2+'%')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE T1
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2
  ON T1.VALUE1 LIKE ('%'+ T2.VALUE2 + '%')
```

Specifying what table you are deleting from.